# C++ undefined reference

Tags: c++

My problem is the following :
I have a class A that inherits from an abstract base class. I override all the virtual functions from the base class, and I have a constructor like this :

```
A::A(B* b)
{
this->b=b;
}
```

In the constructor of class B , I have the following piece of code:

```
A* a=new A(this)
```

However this line of code gives the error : undefined reference to 'A::A(B*)'

I have absolutly  no idea why could this be happening , so any suggestion would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: can you give a full definition of the `A` and `B` classes which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: So in the ctor of B you construct an A on the heap, which involves calling B's ctor again? All right, you like to live dangerously. It looks like a linking problem; try cutting out code, reducing A and B to the simplest code that gives the error, then posting it.

Comment: Any chance you are not including the .h file where you define A?

Comment: I'm including the header

Comment: No, in the constructor of B I construct an A, passing B to the constructor of A , so that A has a reference to B

Comment: When you construct an A, you construct a B, because an A is a B. And if the B constructor *always* constructs an A, then you will have a loop. Also, A seems to have a field B* b (otherwise "this->b" makes no sense), which is *not* the same as A *being* a B. Finally, are you sure you want to construct an A in the B ctor?

Comment: @Beta: there's no mentioning of A inheriting B

Comment: If B is not the base, then I have completely misunderstood the problem. (But if the base isn't B, then why involve it at all?)

Answer (score 3):

This is a linker error. You should probably link against the library defining `A::A(A*)`.

Comment: Could you be more specific, of what I have to do ?

Comment: That defends on your environment, i.e. what compiler and/or linker you are using.

Comment: I have no idea about netbeans, but it probably uses `g++` at some point. There has to be some menu to set the linker options. See if you can add `-lLIBRARY_WITH_A` to the linker flags. If `A` is defined in a directory not under something like `/usr/lib` you also need to pass that to the linker with `-LPATH_TO_LIBRARY_WITH_A` (only the directory of the library).

Comment: Sorry, `-lLIBRARY_WITH_A` should of course be without the `lib` and `.so.X.Y.Z` parts of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

you have to include the definition of  A before the definition of B. You must also make a forward declaration of B to use it in A and prevent circular definitions.

```
        class B;

        class A
        {
        public  :
            A(B* b);
        };

A* a=new A(this) // should work at this point
```

Comment: I've included the header of A in the class B, if that's what you means

Comment: Did you implement all abstract members of the base class in A ?